# Get recently ordered products by date in account dashboard page?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, sales-order, order-status

```
<?php $orders = $this->getOrders(); ?>

<div class="dashboard_section dashboard_section--orders" id="orders">
    <div class="heading-group">
        <h2><?php echo $this->__('Recent Orders'); ?></h2>

        <?php if (sizeof($orders->getItems()) > 0): ?>
            <a class="button button--s" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('sales/order/history'); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View All'); ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <?php if ( sizeof($orders->getItems()) > 0 ): ?>
        <div class="scroll-x" data-scroll-x="600">
            <div class="scroll-x_liner">
                <table class="table recent-orders-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><?php echo $this->__('Date'); ?></th>
                            <th><?php echo $this->__('Status'); ?></th>
                            <th><?php echo $this->__('Total'); ?></th>
                            <th><?php echo $this->__('Order #'); ?></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ($orders as $order): ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $this->formatDate($order->getCreatedAtStoreDate(), 'medium'); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $order->getStatusLabel(); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $order->formatPrice($order->getGrandTotal()); ?></td>
                                <td>
                                  <a href="<?php echo $this->getViewUrl($order); ?>"><?php echo $order->getRealOrderId(); ?> - View</a>
                                  <a class="button button--wide" href="#">Track Package</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
```

Currently I am getting order details by date, but I also need products with name,size,color, price,image inside the table . How can I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have $order (Mage_Sales_Model_Order) you can use `$order->getAllItems();`, which will return an array of all of the items on the order as Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item.  Then, from there, you can get the product model (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) for the item using `getProduct()`, which gives you access to all of the product attributes (using magic methods).

Here it is, starting with an order collection:

```
$orders; // order collection

foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $items = $order->getAllItems(); // array of Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $product = $item->getProduct(); // Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
        echo $product->getName(); // you can 'get' any attribute like this
        echo $product->getSize();
        echo $product->getColor();
    }
}
```

EDIT:  To access orders from `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/customer/acco‌​unt/dashboard.phtml`, or any of the sub-templates, you can do the following:

```
$customerEmail = $this->getCustomer()->getEmail();

$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', $customerEmail)
    ->addFieldToSelect('*');
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim.This works, But, I want to change my renderer/default.phtml file, so that same UI can get on account page and order page. I want only image, image url, product url, for displya in front end on both account page and order page. So any solution?

Comment: @SushantThorat I'm glad this worked, but I'm not sure about what you are asking now.  Are you asking how to access image, image url, and product url?

Comment: I have ordred product table in order page, I want that same table on account dashboard page. How can I gat this? Pleas suggest any solution ASAP.Thanks.

Comment: @SushantThorat Please see edit to my answer.